# Implementation of Step Progress Bar with loop

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, design

I have a indicator that tells user in which step they are:

[image]

Suppose, we are registering televisions we have at home. For the most of the cases, they have just one. However, for some people -let say 1/3 of the cases- it should be somehow allowed to add more. This is the main idea of having a loop for my step progress bar. At some point, they should be allowed to add more entities by following the same steps (e.g. max 5 times) and go further to complete the whole story.

If our loop starts from step 1 to step 3 (e.g. television details, adres of customer and a small survey) and if the steps 4 and 5 are common steps (like paying, confirmation etc):

[image]

Is there a common way/standard to implement such a situation? Or a loop within a step progress completely wrong choice (then what can be the alternative)? I also couldn't see any example for step progress bar with a loop on web.

Comment: I would not make it a loop; this implies the entire process is restarted. If there's an option to add multiple things, like devices, enable users to add these in for example step 1, and in step 2 and beyond they'll just have to fill in multiple extra fields that are associated with these extra devices. You'll likely not find any examples of a progress bar loop because it is counter intuitive. Progress bar means always going forward, looping means you go back and forth.

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing is two nested wizards, one for the whole process and one for entering TVs. I would recommend against this beacuse it will confuse the users.

Keep one wizard for the whole process and have one step for adding TVs. The Add TVs step will have all the necessary fields for entering a TV and a button "I have more TVs" ([Progressive disclosure](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/progressive-disclosure/) design pattern). IF the user clikcs on the "I have more TVs", display a grid with the existing TV and a button to add more TVs.

Comment: Would you still make "adding TV" just one step if that step is very longer than other steps? Or then would you take another way?

Comment: @Asqan It does not matter if the step is longer than the other steps, you can still apply good UX principles within that step to make it as simple as possible. However, entering TV details does not seem a complicated step. It will be a little more complicated for that 1/3 that will have to add more than one.